# Prove these bounds on $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4n^2 -1}{e^n}$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, improper-integrals

I already found this series converge but I don't know how to prove this inequality:
$$ \frac{39}{e^2} \le  \left[\sum_{n=1}^\infty   \frac{ (4n^2 -1)}{e^n}\right] - \frac{3}{e} \le \frac{54}{e^2} $$

All I've found out is that  $\int_{2}^{\infty} \frac{ (4n^2 -1)}{e^n} = \frac{39}{e^2}$

And I don't know what to do next to prove it.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: your sum does converge and hase the sum $$\frac{-1+6 e+3 e^2}{(e-1)^3}$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. One may recall that (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/338852/find-a-closed-form-of-the-series-sum-n-0-infty-n2xn/338860#338860))
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^n=\frac{x}{1-x}, \qquad 
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^2x^n=\frac{x^2+x}{(1-x)^3}, \qquad |x|<1,
$$ giving, by putting $x=\dfrac 1e$,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty   \frac{ (4n^2 -1)}{e^n}=\frac{3e^2+6e-1}{(e-1)^3}=\color{blue}{\frac3e}+\color{red}{\frac{15e^2-10e+3}{e(e-1)^3}}.
$$