# How to evaluate $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty n^3x^n$, for $x\in[0,1)$.

Tags: calculus, summation, power-series

How can I solve the following sum?

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^3x^n$$

For $x\in[0,1)$. Do I have to try values and see if its a geometric series or something like that?

Or do I have first find the differentiation of this?

Comment: Try to differentiate thrice...

Comment: is it n^4x^(n-1) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find a closed form of the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n^2x^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/338852/find-a-closed-form-of-the-series-sum-n-0-infty-n2xn)

Comment: @piancaStrict I believe DonAntonio means differentiating the standard geometric series, not your series.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to see your series' convergence radius is $\;1\;$ , just the same as the well-known standard geometric series. Thus your convergence interval is $\;(-1,1)\;$, and within this interval you can differentiate termwise the geometricseries:

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n\implies f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1}\implies f''(x)=\sum_{n=2}^\infty n(n-1)x^{n-2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(n^2-n) x^{n-2}\implies$$

$$\implies f'''(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n(n-1)(n-2) x^{n-3}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(n^3-3n^2+2n) x^{n-3}+$$

Thus, your series can be put as

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^3 x^n=x^3f'''(x)+3x^2f''(x)+xf'(x)$$

And since $\;f(x)=\cfrac1{1-x}\;$ , then $\;f'(x)=\cfrac1{(1-x)^2}\;$ and etc....

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
n^3 = {} & \overbrace{n(n-1)(n-2)}^\text{3rd degree} {}+{} \overbrace{3n(n-1)}^\text{2nd degree} {}+ n  \\[12pt]
n^3 x^n = {} & \Big(n(n-1)(n-2)x^{n-3} \cdot x^3\Big) \\
& {} + \Big( 3n(n-1) x^{n-2}\cdot x^2 \Big) + \Big( n x^{n-1} \cdot x\Big) \\[12pt]
= {} & x^3 \frac {d^3} {dx^3} x^n + 3x^2 \frac {d^2} {dx^2} x^n + x \frac d {dx} x^n \\[12pt]
\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^3 x^n = {} & x^3 \frac {d^3} {dx^3} \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n + 3x^2 \frac {d^2} {dx^2} \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n + x\frac d {dx} \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n
\end{align}
and this sum has a simple closed form.

Answer (score -1):

One can aproach the series $\sum_{n=0}^∞ n^3x^n$ as the definite integral $\int_0^ {∞} x^3a^x dx $
for a between $0$ and $1$ and solving it we get the expression $6/ln^4(a)$.

Comment: (Not the downvoter). This isn't wrong but it is not justified *why* we are able to swap the sum operator for the limit operator; this isn't true in all cases. You are also spoon-feeding an answer to a low-effort question, which causes people to use the site to do their homework for them.