# Determine the generating function for the sequence $a_n = 2^n n^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

This is an exercise in my course notes.

> **Exercise 3.1** : Find the generating function for the sequence $a_{n}=2^{n}n^{2}$. Hint: Look at the solutions to the generating functions $\displaystyle\frac{1}{(1 - 2x)^{k}}$ and the fact that $n^{2}$ can be written in terms of $\displaystyle\binom{n}{2}$, $n$, and $1$.

I think I have made some progress towards the solution but I haven't gotten all the way. I will present my work below.

I *think* that the "term formula" for a generating function $\frac{1}{(1 - 2x)^k}$ is $a_n = \binom{n - 1 + k}{n}2^n$.

I figure I'm going to have to pick a value of $k$ to solve this problem. If I let $k = 2$, then the binomial coefficient becomes $\binom{n + 1}{n} = n + 1$. If I let $k = 3$ then the binomial coefficient becomes $\binom{n + 2}{n} = \frac{(n + 2)(n + 1)}{2}$. I'm leaning towards $k = 3$ at the moment but I'm not sure.

Regarding the hint about $\binom{n}{2}, n$ and $1$, I looked at the fact that $\binom{n}{2} = \frac{n^2 - n}{2}$, and I then added $\frac{n^2 + n}{2}$ in order to make it equal $n^2$. Thus I determined that $n^2 = \binom{n}{2} + \binom{n + 1}{2}$.

I thought there might be some binomial coefficient identity that I could take advantage of here, but I didn't see anything relevant at Wikipedia. I think I need to somehow manipulate $\binom{n - 1 + k}{n}$ and $\binom{n}{2} + \binom{n + 1}{2}$ into the same thing, and/or maybe multiply $\frac{1}{(1 - 2x)^k}$ by some constant. I'm not sure what to do, though.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/338852/find-a-closed-form-of-the-series-sum-n-0-infty-n2xn)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your observation is right.

**Hint:** Take a look at
$$
\frac{2}{\left( 1-2x \right) ^3}-\frac{3}{\left( 1-2x \right) ^2}+\frac{1}{1-2x}
$$

Compare the coefficients.

Comment: I think this is the easiest solution to understand, for me. You just look at $(n + 2)(n + 1)2^n$ and try to subtract the extra terms by adding/subtracting other generating functions. Thank you. I still don't understand the hint about $n^2, \binom{n}{2}, n$ and $1$, but your way makes sense so I'll take what I can get for now. Thanks again.

Comment: My pleasure. Please accept XD

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* $\sum n^2 z^n =  \dfrac{z (z + 1)}{(1-z)^3}$ and take $z=2x$.